# How to fix the input on this text

Tags: python-3.x, curl, input, printing, pi

```
digit= open('pi.txt','r')
guess = digit.readline()
while guess.isdigit():
    if digit == ".":
        digit = pi.read(1)
    elif digit == "\n":
        seed += 1
        pi.seek(seed)
        digit = pi.read(1)
    else:
        if int(guess) == int(digit):
            print(guess, "is correct")
            correct += 1
        else:
            print("Sorry, number is", digit, "not", guess)
            wrong += 1
    guess = input("enter another digit guess or \"q\": ")
    digit = pi.read(1)


print("\nThanks for playing\nNumber Correct:", correct, "\nNumber Incorrect:", wrong)
pi.close()
```

OUTPUT:

```
Thanks for playing
Number Correct: 0 
Number Incorrect: 0
```

Need to figure it out how to add numbers for the number correct and incorrect and I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow ! one problem I see is `correct` and `wrong` are not defined in your code. You need to add `correct = 0` and `wrong = 0` before while loop

Answer (score 0):

& Hope this help!

1. Maintain two lists `correct_responses` and `incorrect_responses`

```
correct_responses = []
incorrect_responses = []

while guess.isdigit():
    if digit == ".":
        digit = pi.read(1)
    elif digit == "\n":
        seed += 1
        pi.seek(seed)
        digit = pi.read(1)
    else:
        if int(guess) == int(digit):
            print(guess, "is correct")
            correct += 1
            correct_responses.append()
        else:
            print("Sorry, number is", digit, "not", guess)
            wrong += 1
    guess = input("enter another digit guess or \"q\": ")
    digit = pi.read(1)


print("\nThanks for playing\nNumber Correct:", correct, "\nNumber Incorrect:", wrong)
pi.close()
```